# RSelenium Firefox click button

Tags: r, selenium

I want to start an rselenium session with firefox and automatically install an adblocker addon.

```
library(RSelenium)    #Web driver
rem_session <- rsDriver(browser = c("firefox"), port = 4467L)
rem_session$client$navigate("https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/adblock-for-firefox/?utm_source=addons.mozilla.org&utm_medium=referral&utm_content=search")
installButtonaddon <- rem_session$client$findElement(using = "css selector", ".AMInstallButton-button")
installButtonaddon$clickElement()
```

After i click the install button, there is a popub in firefox were i am supposed to click the add button [image]
How can i automatically click that button? It has no css selector or something like that as far as i know. Any help appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Edit: One way seems to be to set up an firefox profile. Still welcome any help!